# Web scraping with beautiful soup for finding animals

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a dog from a search engine site 
in my example it is Pomeranian
I am not sure what should come in the `soup.find_all`

this is what I did :

```py
url = "https://www.winwin.co.il/Animals/Search/SearchResults/AnimalPage.aspx?search=f1b130870fcd32672a71e39ae8e26898"


response = requests.get(url)


data = response.text


soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

dog=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"ContainerSEOTxt"})
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: in the old version, we use findAll now  find_all, check version too

Comment: Boris has the correct answer below, also to save space, it's easier to add the following: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

Answer (score 2):

the result fo find_all must be array of item

```
soup.find_all("a")

 print output

 [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

or

```
divs = soup.find_all('div', 'class_name')
```

if you have more than one class names, just pass the list of class names as parameter

```
divs = soup.find_all('div', ['class1', 'class2'])
```